# JSON.parse().replace() delivers different result than str.replace()

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am a bit confused by the following code snippet. I would expect the result to be the same:

```
// # Base for all, used in method 1 directly
const content = `Amazon, bezahlte EUR 75.60 am Amazon
 Heute ausgegeben: EUR 75.60`

// # Base for method 2
const newString = JSON.stringify(content)
const replaceString = newString.replace('\n', ',')

// # Base for method 3
const newReplaceString = content.replace('\n', ',')

// # Output from method 1
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content).replace('\n', ',')));
> "Amazon, bezahlte EUR 75.60 am Amazon
 Heute ausgegeben: EUR 75.60"

// # Output from method 2
console.log(replaceString)
> ""Amazon, bezahlte EUR 75.60 am Amazon\n Heute ausgegeben: EUR 75.60""

// # Output from method 3
console.log(newReplaceString)
> "Amazon, bezahlte EUR 75.60 am Amazon, Heute ausgegeben: EUR 75.60"
```

Why is the replace function on the stringified object not the same? What do I need to do differently?

Comment: How did you debug this? Doing it step-by-step reveals the problem. `JSON.stringify(content)` escapes the newline, so it's converted into `"\n"`. The matching pattern changes to `"\\n"`, the `\\` is to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 3):

The newline character `\n` (one character) becomes two characters `\` and `n`, you should be replacing it like so:

```
const replaceString = newString.replace('\\n', ',');
```

If you can see the actual character source in the string in the console (i.e. the backslash `\` itself followed by whatever character after it) that means that the character is actually broken into two characters.

Comment: Interesting, I would have expected that the replace function would then replace `\\n` with `\,`, but it doesn't. It kind of makes sense to me now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Spurious that's when it gets tricky: `\n` is one character, `\\n` is two. `JSON.stringify` escapes newlines too: `\n` becomes \ (backslash) followed by n (the letter n).